# How to create a hyperlink which will download the file in FF, Chrome

Tags: firefox, download

I wanna create a link and on click which will start downloading that file. When am putting just file path it is working on Chrome, Android, even on IE but no on IOS, Firefox.

Any ideas why?

Here what i have done

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php $shortVideoLink = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'music_record_link', true );if ( ! empty( $shortVideoLink ) ) {echo $shortVideoLink;} ?>" class="downdloadbtnlink">
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Sure i had updated my question @TechTreeDev